# Tab control like Google Chrome tabs?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms

Any help on existing tab control like Chrome tabs?

I have been searching all over for mutitabs control that allows dragging each tab, with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked for something similar a while back and ended up building my own.  There are docking frameworks out there, but that was not what I was looking for.

I used the [FabTab on codeplex](http://fabtab.codeplex.com/) as a starting point. I removed the features we didn't want and added others, like dragging from one tab control and dropping it on a second to move the tab, and having tabs on all 4 sides at once, if desired.

Comment: So, why did you post an answer if you're not willing to give info?

Comment: check out http://fabtab.codeplex.com/ for a good open source project that might give you a nice starting point. Sorry, that other comment was actually for  a different answer for a different question.

Comment: The only thing compelling about the tabs in Chrome IMHO is the way they "tear off" into separate windows.  I love being able to drag a tab onto my desktop to open the content in a new, separate window.  And then being able to drag it back into any other Chrome browser and have it be added automatically to the list of tabs is really cool.  FabTab doesn't seem to have anything like this.  I crashed the demo app several times by trying different things.

Comment: yeh, I love that aspect of chrome too. I used fabtab as a decent starting point and demo code.

Answer (score 5):

I know I am very late to the party but after working on multiple projects where I implemented this I have started a new open source library:

- https://github.com/ButchersBoy/Dragablz/
- https://dragablz.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for WPF or WinForms? DevExpress and Infragistics both have tabbed MDI controls for WinForms. They seem designed to replicate the Visual Studio tabs, but you should be able to customise them to match Chrome.

**Edit:** as an open-source starting point you could try [the one by Weifen Luo](http://dockpanelsuite.sourceforge.net/). It doesn't seem as customisable as the commercial ones, although I believe it supports rearrangement by dragging.

Comment: I use Infrajistics, the problem is I can't drag a separate tab!

Comment: Hmm... I don't have Infragistics in front of me to check